# Как указать длину пустого двумерного массива?

Tags: java, массивы

Имеется задача по написанию метода, который возвращает максимальное значение в двумерном массиве. Смысл выполнения ее мне понятен. Но там имеется доп. условие. 
"Для пустого двумерного массива возвращает Integer.MIN_VALUE.". Вопрос. хочу использовать ветвление if-else, но не могу понять, как в свойстве if(/указать длину пустого массива){}?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public int maxValue(final int[][] arr) {
    if (arr.length == 0){
        return Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    }
    ....
}
```

двумерный массив это массив массивов, и вы точно так же можете проверить его длину как и одномерного на равенство 0